# bootstrap carousel fit screen don't get it working

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

Sorry, the 1754th question to this topic. I looked at quite a lot but still I don't get it working. From the various answers I came up with the following test case.

It keeps the aspect ratio but makes the picture full width, even if it is in portrait. However, portrait should have the available 100vh height and then some space to the left and right.

I saw frequently that this is hard to do without a background image. Unfortunately I didn't see how to do it with a background image. If this is easier, I would stretch a pixel.

CSS / HTML

```css
.full-size-carousel.carousel { height: calc(100vh - 56px);}
.full-size-carousel.carousel-inner,.full-size-carousel.carousel-item { height: 100%;}
.full-size-carousel.carousel-item img { height: 100%; object-fit: cover; object-position: center;}
```

```html
<body>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="albumCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">  
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item full-size-carousel active">      
        <img src="https://www.americanexpress.com/de-de/amexcited/media/webp/de-de/amexcited/media/cache/article_intro_hero/cms/2023/01/grand-canyon-titelbild.webp?352612" class="d-block w-100" > 
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item full-size-carousel">
        <img src="https://www.dds-online.de/wp-content/uploads/4/9/498673.jpg" class="d-block w-100">  
      </div>                
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#albumCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#albumCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  </div>
  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

This example did not work in a Bootstrap 5 sandbox (instead it worked as stated above) nor did my real code worked on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else becomes desperate on this, I finally did it with js/jQuery.

I simply modify the following image tag based on the aspect ratios of image and available screen/window size:

`<img src="myImg.jpg" class="carouselImage d-block w-100" >`

```js
// Get width/height on page load and add listener
setSize();
window.addEventListener("resize", onResizeInstant);

function onResizeInstant() {
    setSize();
}

function setSize() {
    const heightHeader = 20;        
    const carouselImages = $('.carouselImage');
    var addClass;
    var removeClass;
    
    carouselImages.each(
        function(){     
            const imgHeightInit = $(this).height();
            const imgWidthInit  = $(this).width();
            const imgAspectRatio = imgWidthInit/imgHeightInit;
            
            const windowHeight = window.innerHeight - heightHeader;
            const windowWidth  = window.innerWidth;
            const windowAspectRatio = windowWidth/windowHeight;
            
            if(windowAspectRatio > imgAspectRatio) {
                addClass = 'h-100';
                removeClass = 'w-100';
                imgHeight = windowHeight;
                imgWidth = imgAspectRatio * imgHeight;
            } else {
                addClass = 'w-100';
                removeClass = 'h-100';
                imgWidth = windowWidth;
                imgHeight = imgWidth / imgAspectRatio;
            }
            $(this).addClass(addClass).removeClass(removeClass);
    })
}
```